# Function call after body.onload returns unwanted result

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem:

```
<body>
<script>
function myfunction(y) {
    alert(y);
    }

var x = "1";
myfunction(x);
</script>
</body>
```

This script gives me the desired result: 1
However, the script is executed in my code only with document.body.onload:

```
<body>
<script>
document.body.onload = function myfunction(y) {
    alert(y);
    }

var x = "1";
myfunction(x);
</script>
</body>
```

But in this case the result is not 1, but [object Event]. What do I have to do to get 1 as result?

Comment: You already have it working in the first set of code. That's what you have to do to get 1 as a result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean:

```js
function myfunction(y) {
  alert(y);
}
document.body.onload = function() {
  var x = "1";
  myfunction(x);
}
```

Basically, if you set `onload` as you function which takes a parameter - the argument will be event itself, not the value you tried to provide to it

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)